# Editing the $page variable

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I am using Laravel with Inertia and I would like to be able to filter what is shown with the `$page` variable.

I notice that I can add to it:

```
       return Inertia::render('Some/Route', [
            'add'  => $new_stuff,
            'more' => $more_stuff,
        ]);
```

But I cannot figure out how to remove stuff that is automatically added by Inertia.

What is the best way to handle this?

This is the current output:

```
{ "flash": { "success": null, "update": null, "refused": null, "warning": null }, "errors": {}, "jetstream": { "canCreateTeams": false, "canManageTwoFactorAuthentication": false, "canUpdatePassword": true, "canUpdateProfileInformation": true, "flash": [], "hasApiFeatures": true, "hasTeamFeatures": false, "managesProfilePhotos": true }, "user": { "id": 1, "first_name": "james", "last_name": "smith", "email": "james@smith.io", "email_verified_at": null, "profile_photo_path": null, "created_at": null, "updated_at": "2021-09-04T16:40:52.000000Z", "profile_photo_url": "https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=JS&color=7F9CF5&background=EBF4FF", "profile": { "id": 1, "user_id": 1,  "created_at": null, "updated_at": null}, "two_factor_enabled": false }, "errorBags": [], "currentRouteName": "welcome" }
```

For example, I might want to hide `user : id`.

I have found that jetstream is loading it's own middleware. This can be edited in a vendor file:

`platform/vendor/laravel/jetstream/sorc/Http/Middleware/ShareInertiaData.php`

but I believe I am not supposed to be editing vendor files.

I have tried @Kirk_Beard 's suggestion which is to edit the `app/Http/Middleware/HandleInertiaRequests.php` however, this only seems to allow me to add additional data and not remove/hide data.

Comment: What are you trying to remove from it?

Comment: If you're referring to the [shared data](https://inertiajs.com/shared-data), that's handled in `app/Http/Middleware/HandleInertiaRequests.php` in the `share()` method.

Comment: @KirkBeard This does look like what I am after. However, I do not have the `HandleInertiaRequests.php` file in my Middleware folder.

Comment: @KirkBeard I see a `ShareInertiaData.php` file in the Inertia Vendor file. Is there a way of publishing this into my app folder and using the published version instead?

Comment: If that file is not present, then you need to complete the Middleware section of the [installation instructions](https://inertiajs.com/server-side-setup) by running `php artisan inertia:middleware` and updating your `App\Http\Kernel.php` file.

Comment: @KirkBeard thanks. I have done what you have written. Please have a look at me edited question. I think the problem I have is that jestream is loading the middleware and I can only seem to change that by editing the vendor file. The inertia middle ware only allows me to add more data. Is there a way to override what jestream is doing? I appreciate your help!